# What do "базовая линия" and "профиль" mean in this text?

Tags: транслитерация

I've been trying to get a good translation of a Russian programming article. I more or less get the gist of what it is saying through google translate but some parts come out badly translated. Below is the original Russian and below that is the "rough" translation.

> Динамическое программирование по профилю
>
> [...]Заметим, что для базовой линии номер 1 существует единственный
>   профиль (то есть битовая карта, удовлетворяющая условиям профиля) —
>   карта незаполненного столбца.Ответ на вопрос задачи будет записан в
>   a[m+ 1, 0]. Ошибкой бы было считать правильным ответом число a[m, 2n −
>   1], так как в этом случае не учитывается возможность класть
>   вертикальные доминошки в последнем столбце (см. второй пример).
>   Обсудим «странные» условия на доминошки при получении одного профиля
>   из другого. Казалось бы, забыт еще один тип доминошек, которые могут
>   участвовать при формировании нового профиля, а именно полностью
>   лежащие в столбце i + 1. Дело в том, что если разрешить их, то
>   некоторые способы замощения будут считаться более одного раза.
>   Например, пусть n = 2,m = 2. Т огда d[0][3] = 2, так как можно
>   положить либо две вертикальные доминошки, либо две горизонтальные.
>   Аналогично, d[3][3] = 1 (можно положить одну вертикальную). В итоге

which "translates" to

> Dynamic programming on profile
>
> Note that the baseline number 1 there is a unique profile (i.e. a
>   bitmap that satisfy the conditions of profile) card blank column. The
>   answer to the problem will be recorded in a[m+ 1, 0]. The error would
>   it was considered the correct answer among a[m, 2n − 1], as in this
>   the case is not taken into account the possibility to put vertical
>   dominoes in the last column (see second example). Discuss "strange"
>   conditions on dominoes when you receive one profile from another.
>   Seemingly forgotten one more type of dominoes that can participate in
>   forming a new profile, namely completely lying in column i + 1. The
>   fact is that if you allow them, some ways of tiling will be considered
>   more than once. For example, let n = 2,m = 2. Then d [0][3] = 2,
>   because you can put two vertical dominoes, or two horizontal.
>   Similarly, d [3][3] = 1 (you can put one vertical). In the end

I'm not sure what `профилю`is supposed to be in English. The word "profile" seems unnatural in this sense. Also, `для базовой линии`doesn't make sense to me. Would someone be willing to give a rough translation of this paragraph for me. I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Maybe профиль here can be translated as "layout" or "conditions that layout has to conform". Also "card blank column" should be "a (bit)map of unfilled column". Карта has both map and card meanings, but in the context of the article it should be Map and not Card.

Comment: @Quassnoi♦ I don't think your edit is appropriate. I am after all asking for a translation of the paragraph.

Comment: The definition is in the article. As for English counterpart, this site is not about English language. But how about _slice_ for _профиль_? On second thought, Artemix's layout might work better.

Comment: Did you try writing to the authors at forum? http://informatics.mccme.ru/moodle/mod/forum/view.php?id=331
I suppose they will be so surprised to have international interest to their article, so they might consider translation.
Words "profile" and "baseline" without a context are not clear for native speaker too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [this article](http://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/book/print.php?id=290&chapterid=73) "базовая линия" is a line between squares, it could be translated as "grid line" or "dividing line".

The word "профиль" is used in a sense like "topographic profile", a cross-sectional view of the matrix.

So, it says that the cross section in the 1st grid line can only be an empty bitmap. The final result will be in a[m+1, 0]. One can make a mistake of not considering vertical dominoes in the last column and using a[m, 2n−1] instead, etc... (The rest seems OK.)

Comment: Thank you! The link you posted is actually the same document I have. Do you know if an English Translation exists?

Comment: Don't know, I just googled the text you've posted. :)